# Simple Harmonic Motion under Periodic disturbing force

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

> **A particle of mass $m$ is executing a SHM in a straight line under an acceleration $n^2 \times (distance)$. If a periodic force $mk \cos{pt}$ be introduced and the time period of forced vibration becomes increased $2\frac{1}{2}$ times, then show that $$25p^2=4n^2.$$**

The equation of motion is
$$m\ddot{x}=-mn^2x+mk \cos{pt}$$

The general solution of this differential equation can be obtained as
$$x=a\cos{(nt+\epsilon)}+\frac{k}{n^2-p^2}\cos{pt},~~ for~~p\ne n$$ and
$$x=a\cos{(nt+\epsilon)}+\frac{k}{2p}t\sin{pt},~~for ~~p=n$$
$a$ and $\epsilon~$ are constants.

**How to go further to get the desired answer?** Please help.

Comment: Is your solution up to this part correct?

Comment: @Ganymede Yes, I think so. The general solution is correct.

Comment: Have you used the factor $2\dfrac{1}{2}$ yet?

Comment: @Ganymede No, only I have solved the differential equation.

Comment: You may want to look up on google about the theory or solution of key problem in periodic simple harmonic under disturbing force since you may miss some thing big here...

Comment: @Ganymede The solution of the ODE is correct. There is no mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the forced vibration, the period would be $T_1=\frac{2\pi}n$. With the forced vibration the period becomes $T_2=\frac{2\pi}p$. This is a simplification, but close enough to be useful.

Set $\frac{T_2}{T_2}=\frac52$ and square. Squaring is necessary because we know about the magnitude; $p$ or $n$ could be negative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Without the forced vibration $T_1$ is OK to me (as $k=0$). But with the forced vibration as $$x=a\cos{(nt+\epsilon)}+\frac{k}{n^2-p^2}\cos{pt}$$, both cos terms are there. Then how $T_2$ depends only on $p$ and not on $n$?

Comment: With the forced vibration, why the time period is not equal to $T_3=lcm(T_1, T_2)$?(as if $f(n)$ & $g(n)$ have period $a$ and $b$ then period of $f(n)+g(n)$ is $lcm(a,b)$.)

Comment: When you add two waves with different frequencies, the resultant motion all depends on their relative amplitudes. the motion may continue to be at the same original frequency but with a little wiggle added on, or the forcing vibration may dominate. In this case we know the frequency changes because the question says so, therefore the motions becomes dominated by the added vibration. We therefore can assume that $a<<\frac k {n^2-p^2}$.