# Simple Harmonic Motion in case of periodic force

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics

A particle is execution SHM in a straight line under the acceleration $kx$. If a periodic force of $ml$  cos $pt$ be introduced and time period of forced vibration increased to $1.5$ times then show that $$9p^2=4k$$

Here is a similar type of problem [Simple Harmonic Motion under Periodic disturbing force](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415479/simple-harmonic-motion-under-periodic-disturbing-force)
.

But I do NOT understand how $T_2$ depends only on $p$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your questions seems to be almost the same as the question you link to. Have you read the answer and the comments below it?

Comment: Yes. But I do NOT understand why $T_2$ depends only on p and not on $\sqrt{k}$? Is there a mathematical explanation to this?

Comment: In general you are correct, $T_2$ does depend on $k$. But as @tomi says in the comment, "When you add two waves with different frequencies, the resultant motion all depends on their relative amplitudes. the motion may continue to be at the same original frequency but with a little wiggle added on, or the forcing vibration may dominate. In this case we know the frequency changes because the question says so, therefore the motions becomes dominated by the added vibration. "